# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, compiler-errors, fftw

I have a old sample of c programme that uses fftw to solve differential equations.

two lines of the programme which give error while compiling are:

```
creal(comp[i2+n_y*i1]) = c_zero + 1/15;
cimag(comp[i2+n_y*i1]) = 0.0;
```

Here,
comp is a complex variable with creal, cimag being its real and imaginary parts. It is trying to assign value at some point(i2,i1).

which gives error

```
 **error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment**
```

I had this problem earlier also and fix was to replace `creal` with `__creal__` or something, though I am not able to remember it. Can anyone tell me how can I get rid of the error? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This `1/15` also really looks strange. This would be integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign value to a complex number I did following which worked

```
__real__(comp[i1+n*i2]) = ...
__imag__(comp[i1+n*i2]) = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

`creal` is a function, it returns a value and you cannot assign anything to a value.

For example, assume `creal` is evaluated to `0.0` it is like if you are trying to do:

```
0.0 = c_zero + 1/15;
```

`creal` is a C standard function:

```
#include <complex.h>
double creal(double complex z);
```

Comment: How can I then access real and imaginary parts of complex variable?

Comment: @alekhine with `creal` and `cimag`. What you want to do is: `comp[i2+n_y*i1] = (c_zero + 1/15) + I * 0.0;`

Comment: and remember that `1/5` is an integer division and it is evaluated to  `0`. Use `1 / 5.0` to have a `double` division.

Answer (score 0):

If you are right, this could be implemented:

```
int * pointer_generator()
{
  return (int *)malloc(8);
 }

int main()
{
  *( pointer_generator() )=123234;
  return 0;
  }
```

This worked. VC++ 2010. 
But where it points? Who knows?

Comment: In the parse tree of this assignment statement, the topmost operator on the left side of the `=` is the `*` dereference operator, which produces an lvalue regardless of whether its operand is an lvalue. Try to write a function that allows `function() = 123234` and you'll find it's not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Since the imaginary part of your new complex value is supposed to be `0` you could just do

```
comp[i2+n_y*i1]= c_zero + 1/15;
```

Complex objects are first class citicens in C and can be assigned to directly.

In case you wanted to add another imaginary part

```
comp[i2+n_y*i1]= c_zero + 1/15 + 78 * I;
```

you'd have to include `complex.h` for `I` to work.

**Edit:** Supposing that `c_zero` is just a `0` typed as complex probably the correct writing would just be

```
comp[i2+n_y*i1]= 1.0/15 + 78 * I;
```